# Android´s keyboard doesn´t appear

Tags: android

I have a problem with android´s keyboard. I have a fragment who has an EditText in the top of the screen and below has a nested fragment that is a QR scanner. When I click on the EditText to write something the keyboard doesn´t appear if I don´t do a long click to my device´s menu button. I am trying to show programatically when I focus the EditText but I´m not able. Here is my code, thank you in advance.

```
EditText caja_edicion =(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textcodigo);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(caja_edicion, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
    caja_edicion.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(caja_edicion, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            } else {
                ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(caja_edicion.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have change to this because I am in fragment but it doesn´t work and I don´t know why:

```
final EditText caja_edicion =(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textcodigo);

                caja_edicion.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(caja_edicion, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                        } else {
                            ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(caja_edicion.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                    }
                });
```